# Parameter names in Javascript arrow functions

Tags: javascript, lambda, promise, arrow-functions

I was reading up on Promise types for Javascript, and I am stumped by the purpose of div in the `.then(...)`

```js
function go() {
  showCircle(150, 150, 100).then(div => {
    div.classList.add('message-ball');
    div.append("Hello, world!");
  });
}

function showCircle(cx, cy, radius) {
  let div = document.createElement('div');
  div.style.width = 0;
  div.style.height = 0;
  div.style.left = cx + 'px';
  div.style.top = cy + 'px';
  div.className = 'circle';
  document.body.append(div);

  return new Promise(resolve => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      div.style.width = radius * 2 + 'px';
      div.style.height = radius * 2 + 'px';

      div.addEventListener('transitionend', function handler() {
        div.removeEventListener('transitionend', handler);
        resolve(div);
      });
    }, 0);
  })
}
```

```css
.message-ball {
  font-size: 20px;
  line-height: 200px;
  text-align: center;
}
.circle {
  transition-property: width, height, margin-left, margin-top;
  transition-duration: 2s;
  position: fixed;
  transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
  background-color: red;
  border-radius: 50%;
}
```

```html
<button onclick="go()">Click me</button>
```

I would like to understand the significance of "div" (though I tried renaming it, and the `.then(...)` works fine, however an anonymous `function ()` does not).

Comment: Div here is the object which is returned when you resolved the promise.

Comment: when you use anonymous function, did you write it like `function(div){...}`? The `div` is not the name of the function. It is the first argument of the anonymous arrow function.

Comment: @jaspreet That makes sense, thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

'div' here in your code `showCircle(150, 150, 100).then(div => { } );` is the data that is returned from your promise function ShowCircle. In general, in an arrow function, anything on the left hand side of your lambda expression (=>) is your input paramaters for the function.

```
div => {
//doSomething here
}
```

is

```
function nameFunction(div){
//doSomething here
    }
```

In a promise *then* case, the input supplied to the function is the return value from the promise. Here the param is named as div and holds the return value from ShowCircle().

Comment: Thank you for explanation! This makes sense now: div is the result that showCircle returned, and then in the code, it adds a message-ball and appends the message to it.